# C# .Net IIS Applications within Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my organization, there is a process where in for every new website/application to be added into the IIS, we have to go through a 6 weeks complex process and waiting. Even after the process completes the team will not have access to IIS. We can only deploy the build files using TFS, web deploy etc.

I have initiated the process for my first application/site in the IIS. I wanted to know if there is a way I can avoid future request/process for new application, by making this upcoming application an application of applications :). Something like child applications. But remember I do not have IIS access. I still have access to my application's web config. I also have the freedom to manage URL structures/patterns.

Either by using multiple routes, multiple projects etc. Just thinking loud. My applications will be of type web api, mvc etc

Any crazy ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find this handy: [Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis).

Comment: Why not making folders in your website with each has it's own config file, that way IIS will think of each one of them as a virtual app.

Comment: @tatigo, I have heard of your idea. But are folders separate applications in that situation?

Comment: yes, you can have them as separate applications. I'll post a complete answer.

Comment: @tatigo, :) you heard my mind crying "gimme the sample code"

Comment: @mason. Thanks that was a very good article. A site with multiple application/virtual directories with individual web configs might help. Have to try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several application roots in IIS, which can be virtual or real directories, under the same site.

Those separate applications will have separate configs and will not inherit each other's settings.

You can access your apps under the same domain, or to be configured to use different domains
http://www.domain.com/app1, http://www.domain.com/app2

They can share the same app pool or be configured to use different.

Since you don't have an access to IIS, I'm not sure how would you configure the app pool or domain, but perhaps  `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace will help doing this from code. It contains managed classes to manage all aspects of IIS, including the configuration . It can be used from .Net or from PowerShell.

[Creating Sites and Virtual Directories Using System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524896.aspx)

[Using IIS Programmatic Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524732%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try a site with multiple applications/virtual directories/folders with individual web configs. Will get back if it works.

Comment: @RavishankarRajendran, did the proposed solution worked?